# Ratchet & Clank: Rift Apart game directstorage problem

Tags: directx

Ratchet & Clank: Rift Apart game
Deleted dstorage.dll with direct storage function in the game folder.
However, the game worked without problems.

It must have been packaged with direct storage compression...
I wonder how the game can run better even after deleting dstorage.dll (improving performance).
Is the direct storage function used in the game in a different way that I don't know about?

I thought it wouldn't work because there was no dstorage.dll file...
but game worked ,  the performance was improved.